# what kind of list can used to find the string element containing the substring I need

Tags: java

what kind of list can used to find the string element containing the substring I need,
I'm aiming to find all the possible strings that came ofter substring,
If I give the program a corps and split it into trigram and bigram model

**example:**
if I need "you are"
give me from the list a"you are good", "you are a", "you are kind"," you are special"
from the text where I split.

this haw I save the list.

words[i] is an array of String (word).

```
HashMap<String,uni> hash1=new HashMap<String,uni>();
HashMap<String,bi> hash2=new HashMap<String,bi>();
HashMap<String,tri> hash3=new HashMap<String,tri>();

         for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
              if( hash1.get(words[i])!=null) {
                  hash1.get(words[i]).setCount(hash1.get(words[i]).getCount()+1);
              }
                  else if(hash1.get(words[i])==null) {
                      hash1.put(words[i], new uni(1,words[i]));
                  }
          }
          for(int i=0;i<words.length-1;i++) {
              if( hash2.get(words[i]+words[i+1])!=null) {
                  hash2.get(words[i]+words[i+1]).setCount(hash2.get(words[i]+words[i+1]).getCount()+1);
              }
                  else if(hash2.get(words[i]+words[i+1])==null) {
                      hash2.put(words[i]+words[i+1], new bi(1,words[i]));
                  }
              
          }
          for(int i=0;i<words.length-2;i++) {
              if( hash3.get(words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2])!=null) {
                  hash3.get(words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2]).setCount(hash3.get(words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2]).getCount()+1);
              }
                  else if(hash3.get(words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2])==null) {
                      hash3.put((words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2]), new tri(1,(words[i]+words[i+1]+words[i+2])));
                  }
          }
```

does hash map help with these or totally wrong

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you have? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever List mechanism you like since it just needs to store the strings. A List Interface would be good, for example: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` and store all the strings in the list. It's your parsing code that retrieves the sub-strings you need. Here is an example - Be sure to read all the comments and if you like, delete those comments from within the method code because it makes the method look huge:

```
/**
 * This method will return a String[] Array containing substring content 
 * related to the supplied Search String. What is returned are string 
 * elements which consist of the Search String plus the related substring 
 * content after the Search String.<br><br>
 * 
 * This method is designed to work against a List Interface of Strings.<br>
 * 
 * @param list (List Interface of String - {@code List<String>}) The List of 
 * strings to process and locate the supplied Search String criteria in. If 
 * a List element string is null or empty then that List element is ignored. 
 * If the List is empty then this method will merely return a zero length 
 * String[] Array.<br>
 * 
 * @param searchString (String) The string to search for and retrieve substring 
 * content of. Null, a Null String (""), a period (.), an exclamation mark (!), 
 * or a question mark (?) <u>can not</u> be supplied here either alone or within 
 * the Search String criteria. Doing so will generate an <b>IllegalArgumentException</b>. 
 * A Single word or multiple words separated with whitespaces can be supplied.<br>
 * 
 * @param endContentOnSentenceEnd (Optional - boolean varArgs - Default is true) 
 * By default this method will only retrieve found Search String substring 
 * content up to the end of a sentence which is implied by either a period (.), 
 * an exclamation mark (!), or a question mark (?). Now you know why you can't 
 * have these characters within a Search String. If you just want to return the 
 * found Search String substring content up to the end of the string being 
 * processed then supply boolean false to this optional parameter. Supplying 
 * nothing implies the default boolean true.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String[] Array) A String[] Array containing all the found substring 
 * content.
 */
public static String[] searchForSubstringContent(final List<String> list, final String searchString,
                                                 final boolean... endContentOnSentenceEnd) {
    /* Make sure the supplied List actually contains something.
       If not then just return a zero length String[] Array. */
    if (list.isEmpty()) { return new String[0]; }
    
    // Make sure the Search String is valid
    if (searchString == null || searchString.isEmpty() || 
                searchString.replaceAll("[^.!?]", "").length() > 0) {
        String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + ls 
                + "searchForSubstringContent() Method Error!" + ls 
                + "Invalid Search Criteria Supplied! (\"" + searchString + "\")" 
                + ls + "Read Method JavaDoc." + ls);
    }
    
    /* A boolean flag to determinie if we should retrieve found Search
       String substring content only up to an End-Off-Sentence character 
       (. ! or ?) or to the end of String. Default true, to sentence end, 
       false to end of string.        */
    boolean getToSentenceEndCharacter = true;   // Default
    
    /* See if the optional varArg parameter name endContentOnSentenceEnd
       actually contains something, you know, like a boolean value. If so 
       the set the getToSentenceEndCharacter variable to that boolean value. */
    if (endContentOnSentenceEnd.length > 0) {
        getToSentenceEndCharacter = endContentOnSentenceEnd[0];
    }
    
    /* Used to acquire an End Index. A regular expression 
       used to get the index of the start of another search 
       string (letter case ignored) or a sentence-end 
       ('.', '!', or '?') character.  */
    //String regexPattern = "(?i)( " + searchString + " )|[.!?]";
    String regexPattern = "(?i) " + searchString + " |[.!?]";

    // A List to hold all the found substrings.
    List<String> foundSubstrings = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Parse the supplied List of Strings for the specified 
       Search String so to acquire the substring content. */
    for (String str : list) {
        if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) { continue; }
        // If getToSentenceEndCharacter is true...
        if (getToSentenceEndCharacter) {
            /* Keep processing the current string until all 
           the Search Strings (if any) have been retieved.  */
            while (str.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                // Get Start Index of the found Search String
                int startIndex = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase());
                /* Get end index (up to a sentence end puctuation).
                   This is where the regular expression above is used. */
                java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
                java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
                int endIndex = str.length();
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    endIndex = matcher.start() + 1;
                    // Make sure the endIndex is valid.
                    if (endIndex < startIndex) {
                        endIndex += startIndex;
                        if (endIndex > str.length()) {
                            endIndex = str.length();
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* Extract the found substring. Ternary operator is used here to
                   deterine which version of substring() method we need to use. 
                   If the endIndex is an unsigned value then we use the two argument
                   varsion. If the endInex value is a signed value the we use the 
                   single argument version.                                */
                String found = (endIndex > 0 ? str.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim() : str.substring(startIndex).trim());
                /* If 'found' actually contains something then add it 
                   to the foundSubstrings List.                */
                if (!found.isEmpty()) {
                    foundSubstrings.add(found.trim());
                }
                /* Modify the current Listed string by removing the 
                   found search String section then allowing to loop 
                   again to see if there is yet another search string
                   eithin the remaining portion of the current string. */
                str = str.substring(endIndex);
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, get to end of entire String.
        else if (str.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
            foundSubstrings.add(str.substring(str.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase())));
        }
        /* Otherwise process next string in List because the
           seach string could not be found in the current one.  */
    }

    // Convert List<String> to String[] Array and return.
    return foundSubstrings.toArray(new String[foundSubstrings.size()]);
}
```

To use this method you might have something like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "You are the greatest",
        "You are a nice Grandpa",
        "This string contains no search string criteria.",
        "Y'all is good but you are still the best! Keep on goin cuz you "
                + "are doin fantastic. A long string so keep on going "
                + "till the end. You are going to be surprised, maybe.",
       "Whoever said you are sad would never realy know YOU ARE not sad.");

// Get substring content attached to the Search String...
String[] found = searchForSubstringContent(list, "you are");

// Display results from returned Array...
for (String str : found) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

The Console window should display:

```
You are the greatest
You are a nice Grandpa
you are still the best!
you are doin fantastic.
You are going to be surprised, maybe.
you are sad would never realy know
YOU ARE not sad.
```